# How to display custom tableviewcell on specific indexpath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview and two different custom cell created.
suppose cell1 and cell2.

Now i want to add cell in tableview like following pattern

cell1

cell1

cell1

cell2

cell1

cell1

cell1

cell2

and so on, i have number of count of data that are displayed in cell1 but i don't know count if cell2 because it should be dymanic count, i mean to say after every 3 cell1 data 4th cell will be cell2

here is my code for tableview

```
#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section{
return [arrayRecipeCategoryNAME count];
//return 22;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 175;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if((indexPath.row % 3) == 0){
    HomeTableViewCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell2;
}
else{
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblRecipeCategory.text = [arrayRecipeCategoryNAME objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblRecipeCategory.font = FONT_COMFORTAA_BOLD(28);
    cell.imgRecipeCategory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayRecipeCategoryImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    return cell;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe detect by the data not by the row. For example: **arrayRecipeCategoryNAME[indexPath.row].cell2 == "some data"**, then return **HomeTableViewCell2** otherwise in contrast, The benefit of this is someday server side change the logic. You win it.

Comment: firstly it should be `if (indexPath.row + 1) % 3 == 0` because `0 % N` is always 0. but the problem is your `arrayRecipeCategoryNAME` which is only for `cell1`. you need to try a different approach

Comment: You can do like.... `if ((indexPath.row+1) % 4 == 0 { // return cell 2 } else{ // return cell 1 } `

Comment: @staticVoidMan ya right, and i dont know count for cell2 because its totally depends on cell1 count divisible by 3, that's where i am stuck right now

Comment: @TejasPatel When does `cell2` appear? and why? does it link to a datasource of its own or takes from `arrayRecipeCategoryNAME` as well? Is it like a header?

Comment: @staticVoidMan yes cell1 ad cell2 both are appears good but cell2 is overlap the cell1, it means when i click on cell2 it will redirect to cell1's indexpath.row position because its overlapping

Comment: The problem with this is that my cell2 custom cell covers items that are in my cell1's data source

Comment: @staticVoidMan cell2 doesn't have data source it has just one label in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the number of rows returned in `numberOfRowsInSection:` must be adjusted to show the extra cells.
Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you need to adjust the array index to match the correct sequence that is to be used for your datasource arrays `arrayRecipeCategoryNAME` & `arrayRecipeCategoryImage`

The following will work for your current design:

```
#define INTERVAL 4

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger count = arrayRecipeCategoryNAME.count;

    NSInteger numberOfUnmappedRows = count / INTERVAL;
    NSInteger totalNumberOfRows = (count + numberOfUnmappedRows);

    return totalNumberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(((indexPath.row + 1) % INTERVAL) == 0) {
        HomeTableViewCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        NSInteger numberOfUnmappedCellsBeforeCurrent = indexPath.row / INTERVAL;

        //Use following as the index for your datasource arrays
        NSInteger translatedIndex = indexPath.row - numberOfUnmappedCellsBeforeCurrent;

        HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.lblRecipeCategory.text = arrayRecipeCategoryNAME[translatedIndex];
        //...
        cell.imgRecipeCategory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", arrayRecipeCategoryImage[translatedIndex]]];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that.

```
var Index = [indexpath.Row] + 1

 if Index%4 == 0
 {
    // return cell 2
 }
 else{
    // return cell 1
 }
```

Comment: this is giving me out out like following

cell1
cell1
cell1
cell1 on top cell2

Comment: its overlap cell1's data

Answer (score 0):

If it is fixed that every fourth cell would be cell2 then try using following code, It may help.

```
    Int *row = indexPath.row + 1
    if(row % 4 == 0){
        HomeTableViewCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell2;
    }
    else{
        HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.lblRecipeCategory.text = [arrayRecipeCategoryNAME objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblRecipeCategory.font = FONT_COMFORTAA_BOLD(28);
        cell.imgRecipeCategory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayRecipeCategoryImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        return cell;
    }
```